# Change color first word of each line with CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to target the first word of each line to change the color to only the first word on it. Right now this is being populated by a `textarea` on the backend.

```
<div class="items">
67 small businesses has worked with us since the beginning of time
<br>
<br>3:1 ratio of apple products to humans
<br>
<br>2400 hours clocked in 2012
<br>
<br>13.7 number of times “So what exactly do you do?” is asked weekly
<br>
<br>1628 number of Starbucks K Cups consumed
<br>
<br>32 collective years of creative experience<br></div>
```

what I am trying to accomplish is to put a `<span>` in front of each first word using `jQuery` or something like so:

```
<div class="items">
    <span class="color">67</span> small businesses has worked with us since the beginning of time
    <br>
    <br><span class="color">3:1</span> ratio of apple products to humans
</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

split on breaks (or newlines ?), and add a span around the first word with a word mathcing regex :

```
$('.items').html(function(_,html) {
    var lines = html.split(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi);
    for (var i=lines.length; i--;) {
        lines[i] = $.trim(lines[i]).replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span class="red">$1</span>')
    }
    return lines.join('<br>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qRNxC/)

Comment: This is a great method - but what if the number has a colon or period after it?

Comment: @Mark - then it's not really a word, and you have to rely on whitespace instead.

Comment: how can I add it that it will include the period and colon?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in a loop:

```
 var firstWord = $(this).text().split(" ")[0];
 var newText = $(this).text().replace(firstWord, "<span class='color'>"+firstWord +"</span>");
 $(this).html(newText);
```

Comment: this only targets the first word in the whole group